# How to set up multiple UIDocumentPickers in the same VC

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpicker

In one VC I am working in there are three buttons, and each button should present a document picker for different types of media. I have this configured-- but what I am not sure how to do is to handle my delegate method

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
```

How can I monitor which document picker set off the delegate method, since every button should handle this function differently? I tried to use `controller.tag`, but this doesn't seem to be a property of a `UIDocumentPickerViewController`. Any pointers would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 3 separate instances of `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in your view controller and check the instance of `controller` in delegate method.

```
private lazy var documentPicker1: UIDocumentPickerViewController = {
    let controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController()
    controller.delegate = self
    return controller
}()

private lazy var documentPicker2: UIDocumentPickerViewController = {
    let controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController()
    controller.delegate = self
    return controller
}()

private lazy var documentPicker3: UIDocumentPickerViewController = {
    let controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController()
    controller.delegate = self
    return controller
}()

func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    
    if controller == documentPicker1 {

    } else if controller == documentPicker2 {

    }
    ...
}
```

Or you could keep a property in `view controller` to track which button was tapped and check it in the delegate method.